# ¿Por qué tipo de dato double redondea?

Tags: java

Cordial saludo

Se me esta presentando un redondeo con el tipo de dato double, es el siguiente caso:

```
public class Prueba {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double dato = 93006701513940021d;
    double dato1 = 93006701513946893d;
    System.out.println(dato);
    System.out.println(dato1);
}
}
```

La salida que me esta presentano es:

```
9.3006701513940016E16 // 
9.3006701513946896E16
```

No comprendo porque los dos dígitos antes de la expresión de notación científica los cambia.

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: El motivo es el que te indica @SJuan76, double no tiene una precisión exacta. Necesitas usar BigDecimal.